# How to create virtual usb key

Tags: linux, usb, debian, python

I have a service that manages a USB key (format, mount/umount, read/write, check space) coded in Python 2. This service call system to manage the device (mount/umount, mkfs, state) and monitor `/proc/mounts` to check mounting status.

There are some tests to check the service behaviour, but I am unable to test the service without a real USB key but it's an issue for Jenkins slaves.

I tried to mount the loop device, but this technic require to modify the service to manage this specific device.

- Do you know some technics to create a virtual device that behaves as a USB key?
- Do you know a way to test this kind of service ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading an article about [Linux-USB Gadget API Framework](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget), I found a way to mount a device as if it was a USB key using loop device ([here](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/file_storage.html)):

1. create a virtual drive :

   ```
    fallocate -l 128M /tmp/virtual_drive.img
   ```
2. attach this as loop device:

   ```
    sudo losetup -o512 /tmp/virtual_drive.img /dev/loop0
   ```

Then this virtual device is used as-is by the service.

Comment: USB Gadgets and `losetup` aren't really related... From your question, I'd suggest that `losetup` alone doesn't achieve what you're after - emulating a USB mass storage device.

Comment: @Attie I am agree with you: what I meant was that by reading an article on USB gadget, I realized that losetup was enough. I was able to simplify the procedure without going as far as emulating the USB key.

Comment: nowadays the command is `losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/my.img` - or instead of specifying the `loop` device use the first free device with `$(losetup -f)`